# LINQ Sum list of items grouped by type inside list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following order object which contains a list of order addons. I am trying to create a report that shows all the addon types and their quantities summed.

```
public class Order {
     public IList<OrderAddon> OrderAddons { get; set; }
}

public class OrderAddon {
     public enum OrderType { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

This is where I am at and can't figure out if the entire query is wrong of I am just missing something.

```
var query = from order in Model.Orders
            from addon in order.OrderAddons
            group order by addon.AddonType
            into orderAddons select new
            {
                 Name = orderAddons.Key,
                 Quantity = orderAddons.Sum(x => x.) << This is where I am stuck
            };
```

When I hit . my intellisense is showing me properties in order object not the addon object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're saying `group order by ...`, so the `orderAddons` object becomes a grouping of `order`s. You can use this if you're going to need properties from both objects:

```
from order in Model.Orders
from addon in order.OrderAddons
group new{addon, order} by addon.AddonType
into orderAddons select new
{
    Name = orderAddons.Key,
    Quantity = orderAddons.Sum(x => x.addon.Quantity)
};
```

If this is all the data you need, this is a little simpler:

```
from order in Model.Orders
from addon in order.OrderAddons
group order.Quantity by addon.AddonType
into quantityByAddonType select new
{
    Name = quantityByAddonType.Key,
    Quantity = quantityByAddonType.Sum()
};
```

Comment: Interesting, learn something new everyday. I did not know I could do that. :)

Answer (score 4):

an alternative syntax same result...

```
var result = Model.Orders
  .SelectMany(order => order.OrderAddons)
  .GroupBy(addon => addon.OrderType)
  .Select(grouping => new
  {
      Name = grouping.Key,
      Quantity = grouping.Sum(addon => addon.Quantity)
  });
```

Comment: 'til the end of my days I will +1 method-chains as a superior option over query-comprehension syntax.

Comment: @KirkWoll yeah i have the same policy!